# Passing arguments from modules to resources in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I added `vpc` module in modules.tf:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "5.0.0"
  name = "my-vpc"
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

  azs             = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1f"]
  private_subnets = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24"]
  public_subnets  = ["10.0.101.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24"]

  enable_nat_gateway = true
  enable_vpn_gateway = true

  tags = {
    Terraform = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

Then I added `aws_vpc_endpoint` to main.tf according to the documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/-/aws/5.0.1/docs/resources/vpc_end, the `vpc_id` argument is required.

How to pass `vpc_id` (or equivalent for VPC ID) argument from the above module to the `aws_vpc_endpoint` resource block?

Based on the basic exemplary usage from the above documentation:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.main.id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.us-west-2.s3"
}
```

I tried to do that through the `for_each` or `count` but without success.

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  for_each = toset(module.vpc.azs.id)
  vpc_id       = each.value
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3"
}
```

I got the error:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 116, in resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3":
│  116:   for_each = toset(module.vpc.azs.id)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.vpc.azs is list of string with 2 elements
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code the `aws_vpc_endpoint` resource should use the module output like this:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id       = module.vpc.vpc_id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.us-west-2.s3"
}
```

The doc you should use is the one related to the module you're using: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest?tab=outputs

Comment: It was so easy, so I am angry with myself. I was looking for Inputs, not Outputs in the docs. Sorry, and really thanks @BapRx.